# How can i move all files in a directory to another using Ansible module?

Tags: ansible

if you're going to move ALL files in a certain folder to another using Ansible, you would use the command module something like:

```
command: mv /home/user/boxA/* /var/www/boxB/
```

But it occurred an stderr saying you cannot move the "/home/user/boxA/*".

I think it should be an easier findable solution .

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps community to focus on unanswered questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `shell` module instead of `command` to use globbing.

```
shell: mv /home/user/boxA/* /var/www/boxB/
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It totally worked. Didnt know there's shell module...